# Angular 2 Error TS2345

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
  selector:'my-app', 
  template:`<h1>Hi there <\h1>
            <my-tut><\my-tut>`, 
  directives :[TutorialComponent] 
})
```

It shows the error:

> Argument of type selector:string template:string; directives :typeof TutorialComponent [] ;} ' is not assignable to parameter of type Component. Object literal may only specify known properties,  and directives does not exist in type Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`directives` parameter has been removed from `@Component` annotation with 2.0.0-rc.6. They are now included in the `@NgModule`

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/4a740f2